# Get the standar deviation each n rows with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, standards, standard-deviation

I'm trying to get the ST of the last 20 values for each row in a data.frame. The procedure would be something like this in excel, but im trying to do it in r and with dplyr. 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N7ddg.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO. It's easier to help you if you make your question reproducible including sample input and expected output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions Check out [mre] and [ask]. Data images are not suitable.

Comment: Hello Daniel. Do you mean each row, or each column? The image shows a calculation across multiple rows, not columns.

Comment: Hello! I made an other post with more information! Sorry! This was my first post. Here is the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61808947/for-each-row-in-a-data-frame-get-the-standard-deviation-of-the-previous-n-value

Answer (score 0):

Your question is thin and does not provide a data source.  But here is an example of what you want.  This is a dataframe with random numbers with 50 rows.  There are two columns of numbers.

The last twenty rows (this is what you want) from that dataframe are selected and then these twenty rows are used within a loop.  A math function is applied to each of these 20 rows.

```
set.seed(14)
n <- sample(100, 50)
b <- sample(200, 50)
cdf <- data.frame(n, b)     # new data frame with random two columns of random numbers.

nrow(cdf)

last <- nrow(cdf) - 20             # Selecting the last 20 rows of data from the data frame

for (i in (last:nrow(cdf)))  {        # loop to apply math to last 20 rows of data.
    print(mean(cdf$b[i]))
    print(i)
    }
```

Comment: Hello! Thanks for answering, sorry for the lack of information, this is my first question here. The problem is that I need the st of the last 20 values for every value from the data. I'll try to make an other post and more specific.

Comment: Hi.  I'd appreciate an up click on this answer I provided.  If I'm around at the time, I'll check on your next question.