# For each row in a data.frame, get the standard deviation of the previous n values

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I am struggling to get the standard deviation of the previous n values. Or in my case the last 5 days.

I have the next code as an example:

```
df<- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2019-12-01"), as.Date("2020-03-31"), by="days"),
                TRM= runif(122, min=3500, max=4100))
> df
          date      TRM
1   2019-12-01 3540.028
2   2019-12-02 3673.536
3   2019-12-03 3827.182
4   2019-12-04 3824.791
5   2019-12-05 3906.753
6   2019-12-06 3528.100
7   2019-12-07 3650.191
# ... with more rows
```

Then I use `mutate` to add some information that I need, I will show you the last rows:

```
df<-mutate(df, diferencia = TRM - lag(TRM, 1),
           VAR=diferencia/lag(TRM, 1))
>df
          date      TRM  diferencia          VAR
118 2020-03-27 3779.479 -262.366328 -0.064912515
119 2020-03-28 3773.771   -5.708207 -0.001510316
120 2020-03-29 4097.078  323.307069  0.085672159 
121 2020-03-30 3752.619 -344.459061 -0.084074332 
122 2020-03-31 3707.442  -45.176979 -0.012038788
```

So what I need is the following:

1. Create a column that have the `sd` for the column "VAR".
2. That the `sd` for each row must contain only the last 5 days of the column "VAR".
3. If all this could be done with `dply`, would be great. (Not necessary)

For example, for the row 122 the result would be this:

```
 > sd(df[118:122,4])
[1] 0.06630885
```

So what I what to get is this value for all the rows of my `df`, I used 5 days as an example but I would like to modify the range:

```
          date      TRM  diferencia          VAR  diff5days
118 2020-03-27 3779.479 -262.366328 -0.064912515 0.05801765
119 2020-03-28 3773.771   -5.708207 -0.001510316 0.04799908
120 2020-03-29 4097.078  323.307069  0.085672159 0.06207932
121 2020-03-30 3752.619 -344.459061 -0.084074332 0.07522609
122 2020-03-31 3707.442  -45.176979 -0.012038788 0.06630885
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution using Base R:

```
df<- data.frame(date = seq(as.Date("2019-12-01"), as.Date("2020-03-31"), by="days"),
                TRM= runif(122, min=3500, max=4100))
df$stDev <- NA

for(i in 5:nrow(df)) df$stDev[i] <- sd(df$TRM[(i - 4):i])
```

...and the output:

```
> head(df,n = 10)
         date      TRM rownum     stDev
1  2019-12-01 3553.666      1        NA
2  2019-12-02 4054.015      2        NA
3  2019-12-03 3976.555      3        NA
4  2019-12-04 3825.628      4        NA
5  2019-12-05 4036.383      5 208.01581
6  2019-12-06 3787.414      6 122.38142
7  2019-12-07 3886.663      7 103.45743
8  2019-12-08 3930.801      8  97.10099
9  2019-12-09 3626.911      9 155.10571
10 2019-12-10 3781.731     10 117.29726
>
```

We can verify the results for the first three rows as follows:

```
> # verify first three results
> sd(df$TRM[1:5])
[1] 208.0158
> sd(df$TRM[2:6])
[1] 122.3814
> sd(df$TRM[3:7])
[1] 103.4574
>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `zoo`'s `rollapply` function for doing this rolling calculation. In `dplyr` you can use this as -

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

df <- df %>% mutate(sd5 = rollapplyr(TRM, 5, sd, fill = NA))
```